# interrupting activity and multiple instances of activity issues

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My problems are hopefully related to each other.  I run a countdown timer service that fires an intent in the onfinish method.  When on finish completes it automatically opens/ bring the app up which I don't want it to do.  why is this so?  id like it to just show the notification.    Also when I click on the notification instead of just resuming the activity it creates another one.   I figured the problems were related to each other due to the intents.  here is the code

from onFinish() not from the notification

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastService.this, MainActivity.class);


            intent.putExtra("id1",id1);

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);



          startActivity(intent);
```

and here is the code for the notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificBuilder.setContentTitle("Loot");
    notificBuilder.setContentText("Claim your Gold now!");

    notificBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gold2);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notificBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
    notificBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent backhome = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    backhome.putExtra("id2",id2);

    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(backhome);
    PendingIntent pd = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    notificBuilder.setContentIntent(pd);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notifID, notificBuilder.build());

    isNoteActive = true;

}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do in `onFinish()`? I'm missing the point here.

Comment: Why are you using `TaskStackBuilder` for the `Notification`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to open your `MainActivity`, then you shouldn't write this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BroadcastService.this, MainActivity.class);
...
startActivity(intent);
```

Opening `MainActivity` is exactly what this does.

Comment: its passing extras is there any way for it to still pass extras and not open

Comment: "Passing extras" only makes sense in the context of opening an activity. By this I mean that what you're doing is (a) opening an activity and (b) sending some extra data to that activity. If you don't want to open an activity, then why are you sending it extra info?